# How to initialize modifiers after loading an object using 'bpy.data.libraries.load'?

Tags: python, modifiers

I'm working on a script that assembles assets from various `blend` files using the `bpy.data.libraries.load` context.

I'm trying to load an object that has various *Vertex Weight* *modifiers*, including *Proximity* to another object.

I have to process the Vertex Weight values after the `libraries.load` call, but, in this case, I find all values set to `1.0`.

If I use the UI to append the same object, and then run the same script, I get my proper Vertex Weight values.

I have the impression that modifiers are not "ready" (evaluated yet) after the `libraries.load` call.

Is there any way to instruct Blender to properly setup the modifiers after a call to `libraries.load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifiers are evaluated by the `Depsgraph`.

AFAIK, the Python API only provides access to the `Depsgraph` of *visible* objects.

After the `load`, the objects must be added to the `bpy.context.scene`, in a way that makes them visible.

Then, their modifiers are properly evaluated when accessed in Python.

I've been testing with the following script.

```py
import bpy

# Load the asset

blendPath = r"C:\temp\plane_vertex_proximity_modifier.blend"
with bpy.data.libraries.load(blendPath, link=False, relative=True) as (data_from, data_to):

    data_to.objects = data_from.objects[:]

# Put the objects loaded in a *visible* collection
# visible is IMPORTANT, so that modifiers are evaluated

my_collection = bpy.data.collections.new('__assets__')
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(my_collection)
layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[my_collection.name]
layer_collection.exclude = False
for obj in data_to.objects:
    my_collection.objects.link(obj)

# Query vertex group values

obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['Plane']

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
eo = obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
mesh = eo.to_mesh(preserve_all_data_layers=True, depsgraph=depsgraph)

vg = eo.vertex_groups['dist']
vg_index = vg.index

class NoGroup:
    weight = 0.0

v_weights = [ 0.0 ] * len(mesh.vertices)
for v in mesh.vertices:
    group = NoGroup
    # IMPORTANT(nll) v.groups can be in any order, or incomplete...
    for g in v.groups:
        if g.group == vg_index:
            group = g
            break
    v_weights[v.index] = group.weight

# values are '1.0' if modifiers are not evaluated
# values are '0.2828...' if modifiers are ok
print("v_weight", v_weights)

# After the evaluation, we can exclude the layer collection

layer_collection.exclude = True
```